# DropDownList - SelectedIndexChanged not triggered when SelectedValue has been set to a different value in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've a `DropDownList` I want to supervise for any changes on the selection, so I subscribed the `SelectedIndexChanged` event like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSource='<%# new string[] { "1", "2", "3" } %>' />
<asp:Button ID="b" runat="server" OnClick="b_Click" Text="Test" />
```

If I change the selection and click the button it will jump in my `SelectedIndexChanged` event. However, if I change the selection in code-behind by setting the `SelectedValue` property of the `DropDownList` the event will not be fired. Here is my code behind to illustrate the problem:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ddl.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ddl.SelectedValue = "2";
}

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Breakpoint here");
}
```

I also tried to cheat by using the `TextChanged` event, but the problem is the same. Then I tried to set the `SelectedIndex` property of the `DropDownList` and was shocked, because not even this works.

Why no change events will be triggered when `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` has been changed on code-behind?

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: just do this after assignment `ddl.ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null)`; it is not automaticc

Comment: @techspider Thanks, yes I know I could call any event subscription manually, but hell this is dirty and it requires to think on it when setting the `SelectedValue`, always. Is there no cleaner way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I tried to use your code but the datasource of your dropdownlist didn't work. Don't wanna loop or manually add them into your DropDownList.Items instead?

Comment: @CurseStacker Yes right, to bind it you have to call `DataBind` first. I changed my question to provide a working code sample.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event only fires if the selected index changes between post events.

> The SelectedIndexChanged event is raised when the selection from the list control changes between posts to the server. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to subscribe to event that fires whenever a property is changed (even programmatically), the traditional way to do that is to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).  The dropdown list control doesn't implement this out of the box, but you can subclass it and implement it yourself, then subscribe to the event.

e.g.

```
class MyDropDownList : DropDownList, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override int SelectedIndex
    {
        set 
        {
            base.SelectedIndex = value;
            PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedIndex"));
        }
        get
        {
            return base.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

...or something like that.  The above may not compile verbatim but you get the idea.

Seems like a waste of time to me.  If your page is so complicated you need to subscribe to events that fire within the same HTTP transaction you're probably overdoing it.